# How to create an UnaryExpression on Math functions as Log, Cos, Sin

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I want to build a list of UnaryExpression to be used later in my code. I was able to easly make it for BinaryExpression and obtained:

```
var binaryList = new Func<Expression, Expression, Expression>[]
        {
            Expression.Add, 
            Expression.Subtract, 
            Expression.Multiply, 
            Expression.Divide
        };
```

In my UnaryExpression list, I want to be able to handle Math.Cos(..), Math.Log(..) as Unary operator. To get the idea I would love to have something like

```
var unaryList = new Func<Expression, Expression>[]
        {
            Expression.Negate, // works fine
            new Func<Expression, Expression>(
                expr => new UnaryExpression(Math.Cos, expr)
        };
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the Expression.Call method?

Comment: Yes I did but I was not able to retrieve the MethodInfo for `Math.Cos`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to create a factory for expressions that represent calling a static method with a given argument. Calling methods is represented by [`MethodCallExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression.aspx), an instance of which can be easily created through the factory method [`Expression.Call`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341086.aspx). Here's how:

```
var unary = new Func<Expression, Expression>(
    e => Expression.Call(null, typeof(Math).GetMethod("Cos"), e));
```

Update: I just realized there is [another overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301084.aspx) of `Expression.Call` that allows you to completely omit the first parameter (instance) when dealing with `static` methods:

```
e => Expression.Call(typeof(Math).GetMethod("Cos"), e)
```

Comment: Just perfect, and so fast. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer the nameof function rather than using magic strings:

```
e => Expression.Call(typeof(Math).GetMethod(nameof(Math.Cos)), e)
```